# UIImageVIew can't load image after Xcode update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

This is a pretty simple code that I use to create a UIImageView. I have used it before and it was working pretty fine before the new Xcode update. After updating the Xcode the simulator just shows a white background

```
MainViewController *mainView = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
UIImageView *view1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selim"]];
if (view1==nil)
{

    NSLog(@"nil");}
else
{
    NSLog(@"not nil");
}
 _window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]
[_window addSubview:view1];
_window.rootViewController= mainView;
_window.rootViewController.view=view1;
```

The funny thing is that I checked if view1 is nil and The console prints that it is "Not nil". What is the source of error can someone try. I have been trying to fix this the whole day but it is not .working

Comment: Assign frame to view1.

Comment: It is not working

Comment: `view1.frame = CGRect(...)` <-- do this.

Comment: It is not working check my answer to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will be better:

```
[mainView.view addSubview: view1];
_window.rootViewController= mainView;
```

instead of

```
[_window addSubview:view1];
_window.rootViewController= mainView;
_window.rootViewController.view=view1;
```